# How to get the value of an observable using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to access to the value of an observable from an other script that the one where the view model is defined, but I've no idea how to do that. Let me explain the thing:

My view model is defined in `monitoringviewmodel.js` and used in `MonitoringTask.cshtml` where I display the data passed from it. In this webpage, I've a select list where the user can choose in which page they want to go. My idea was to store the link in the `value` parameter of each `option`. Then I would get which link the user choosed, and I would use their value to redirect them to the right page. In order to get the right data, I've decided to put an `id` on the `select`to identify it simply (my data are shown using a `foreach`, so I cannot just select the `select` tag bc it apears multiple time in the page). The `id` is put through an observable from `knockout.js`. My problem is that I don't know how to get the value of this observable in a script in my webpage.

If you have any idea how to do that...

Thanks

Comment: Observables are nothing but functions. So you can just do `observableVariable()` to get the value

Comment: Please share your code so that it might be useful for people who will be able to answer your question. Also as @Rajesh mentioned you could use `()` to get the value of the observable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var viewModel = ko.dataFor(element);
var value = viewModel.observable();
```

Answer (score -1):

@Rajesh: the definition of my viewmodel is separated from the webpage. I want to have access the value of my observable from my webpage, that's why I can't just use `observableVariable()` in the script in my webpage.

@frooook : because I use a `foreach` binding, and bc my id is generated in the viewmodel in the `monitoringviewmodel.js` file, I don't have the id of the element.

If the things aren't clear (and bc @samuellawrentz asked me to put it ^^), here's the code I used (it requires the library `require.js` and other bunch of files to work properly, so it won't run as it is, but this is the main part that deals with the data, the rest that is not included works perfectly fine):

`monitoringviewmodel.js` :

```
define([
    'common'
], function () {
    'use strict';
    //1000 ms = 1 second
    var callSmtpCheckTmp = 3600000; // chaque 1 heure
    var callBdCheckTmp = 600000; // chaque 10 min
    var checkServiceTmp = 60000; // chaque 1 min
    var checkFirstSmtpTmp = 60000; // chaque minute
    var checkRunningTmp = 10000; //chaque seconde
    var checkStatusTmp = 60000;// chaque minute
    var ko = require('knockout');

    var ViewModel = function (message) {
        var _this = this;

        _this.listService = ko.observableArray(
            ko.utils.arrayMap(message.ListServiceModel, function (elem) {
                return new ServiceViewModel(elem);
            }));

        var sizeColumns = ComputeSizeColumns();
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.listService(), function(elem) {
            elem.sizeColumns = sizeColumns;
        })

        CheckBdData();

        // All the functions below work perfectly fine and are not releveant to the topic

        function CheckBdData() { ... }

        function ComputeSizeColumns() { ... }

        $(window).load(function () {
            setInterval(CheckBdData, callBdCheckTmp);
        });
    };

    var ServiceViewModel = function (items) {
        var _this = this;

        var checkFirstSmtp = true;
        _this.id = ko.observable(items.Id);
        _this.serviceName = ko.observable(items.ServiceName);
        _this.description = ko.observable(items.Description);
        _this.serviceUrl = ko.observable(items.ServiceUrl);
        _this.status = ko.observable(false);
        _this.checkSmtp = ko.observable(true);

        _this.listTask = ko.observableArray(
            ko.utils.arrayMap(items.ListTaskModel, function (elem) {
                return new TaskViewModel(elem, items.ServiceUrl, items.Id, _this.checkSmtp);
            }));

        _this.profitStatus = ko.computed(function () {
            var css = '';
            if (_this.status() === true) {
                // css = "statusOk";
                css = "glyphicon-ok";
            }
            else {
                // css = "statusKO";
                css = "glyphicon-remove";
            }
            return css;
        });
        _this.sizeColumns = ko.observable("");

        checkStatus();

        // All the functions below work perfectly fine and are not releveant to the topic

        function checkStatus() { ... }

        function CheckSMTPTask() { ... }

        function CheckFirstSMTPTask() { ... }

        $(window).load(function () {
            setInterval(checkStatus, checkServiceTmp);
            setInterval(CheckSMTPTask, callSmtpCheckTmp);
            setInterval(CheckFirstSMTPTask, checkFirstSmtpTmp);
        });
    };

    var TaskViewModel = function (items, serviceUrl, serviceId, checkSmtp) {
        var _this = this;
        var urlTask = serviceUrl + items.DisplayName + "/";
        var errorLinkStr = new Link("Erreurs", "/Monitoring/ViewError?environnementId=" + environnementId + "&serviceId=" + serviceId + "&taskId=" + items.Id);
        var histLinkStr = new Link("Historique", "/Monitoring/ViewHistory?environnementId=" + environnementId + "&serviceId=" + serviceId + "&taskId=" + items.Id);
        var configLinkStr = new Link("Config", urlTask + "config");
        var statusLinkStr = new Link("État", urlTask + "status");
        var IdPopoverStr = 'Popover' + items.DisplayName;
        _this.id = ko.observable(items.Id);
        _this.serviceId = ko.observable(serviceId);
        _this.displayName = ko.observable(items.DisplayName);
        _this.bdName = ko.observable(items.BdName);
        _this.serviceUrl = ko.observable(serviceUrl + items.DisplayName + "/");
        _this.description = ko.observable(items.Description);
        _this.status = ko.observable('');
        _this.nextExecution = ko.observable(items.NextOccurrenceToString);
        _this.nbExec = ko.observable(items.NbExec);
        _this.nbError = ko.observable(items.NbError);
        _this.serviceUrl = ko.observable(items.ServiceUrl);
        _this.lastExec = ko.observable(items.LastExec);
        _this.execTaskLink = ko.observable(urlTask + "exec");
        _this.errorLink = ko.observable(errorLinkStr.link);
        _this.histLink = ko.observable(histLinkStr.link);
        _this.configLink = ko.observable(configLinkStr.link);
        _this.statusLink = ko.observable(statusLinkStr.link);
        _this.runningLink = ko.observable(urlTask + "isrunning");
        _this.isrunning = ko.observable(false);
        _this.checkBdd = ko.observable(false);
        _this.arrayLinks = ko.observableArray([errorLinkStr, histLinkStr, configLinkStr, statusLinkStr]);
        _this.Selectedlink = ko.observable();
        _this.IdPopover = IdPopoverStr;
        _this.IdPopoverCall = "#" + IdPopoverStr;
        _this.PopoverContent = ko.observable("Tâche : " + items.DisplayName+ "\nDescription : " + items.Description);
        _this.profitStatus = ko.computed(function () {
            var css = '';
            if (_this.status() === true) {
                //css = "statusOk";
                css = "success";
            }
            else {
                //css = "statusKO";
                css = "danger";
            }
            return css;
        });
        checkStatus();

        // All the functions below work perfectly fine and are not releveant to the topic

        function checkStatus() { ... }

        function RunningTask() { ... }

        $(window).load(function () {
            setInterval(checkStatus, checkStatusTmp);
            setInterval(RunningTask, checkRunningTmp);
        });

        CheckBddTask(_this);
    };

    var Link = function(name, link){
        this.name = name;
        this.link = link;
    }

    // All the functions below work perfectly fine and are not releveant to the topic

    function CheckStatusTask(task, checkSmtp) { ... }

    function CheckRunningTask(task) { ... }

    function CheckStatusService(service) { ... }

    function CheckSMTPTaskService(service) { ... }

    function CheckBddTask(task) { ... }

    function GetBdInfo(listTask) { ... }

    return ViewModel;
});
```

`MonitoringTask.cshtml`:

```html
<!-- The rest of the webpage works perflectly fine, the part below is the one that deals with the data from knockout.js -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div data-bind="foreach: { data: listService, as: 'service' }">
                <table class="table table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=8 >
                                <h3>
                                    <span data-bind="text: service.serviceName"></span>
                                </h3>
                            </td>
                            <td><span style="font-size:20px;" class="icon-ok-notok glyphicon" data-bind="css: service.profitStatus"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tâche</th>
                            <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Description</th>
                            <th>État</th>
                            <th>Prochaine Exec</th>
                            <th>Dernière Exec</th>
                            <th>Nb Exec</th>
                            <th>Nb Error</th>
                            <th>Forcer l'exec</th>
                            <th>Visualisation</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: listTask, as: 'item' }">
                        <tr data-bind="css: {danger: (!item.status() && $parent.status()), success: !(!item.status() && $parent.status())}">
                            <td>
                                <span data-bind="text: item.displayName"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
                                <span data-bind="text: item.description"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css : {'glyphicon-ok': item.status(), 'glyphicon-remove': !item.status()}"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="noWrap" align="center">
                                <span data-bind="text: item.nextExecution"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span data-bind="text: item.lastExec"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span data-bind="text: item.nbExec"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span data-bind="text: item.nbError"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a data-bind="attr: { href: item.execTaskLink}" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select data-bind="attr: {id: item.displayName}, options: arrayLinks, optionsText: 'name', value: Selectedlink, optionsValue: 'link', optionsCaption:'Visualiser...'"></select><br/>
                                <span data-bind="visible: Selectedlink">Lien : <a data-bind="attr: {href: Selectedlink() ? Selectedlink : '#'}" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></a></span>
                                <span style="display: none;" data-bind="text: item.displayName"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```